# Storing multiple Enum-types in the same field

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I need to store different types of `Enum` into one `EnumProperty`.

```
class Name(ndb.Model):
    foo= msgprop.EnumProperty(SomeEnumType)
```

As seen above, I need to define the exact `Enum`-Type. How can I store different `Enum`-Types in the same `Field`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because, as you observed, the type argument is mandatory.

You *might* be able to take advantage of this note in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#msgprop):

> EnumProperty stores the value as an integer; in fact, EnumProperty is
>   a subclass of IntegerProperty.

Which means storing it as an IntegerProperty (but you may need to add your own runtime sanity checks for the values you assign to it):

```
foo = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Comment: This would not work, as I need to know, of which EnumType the element is.